# Aggregate data with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework

I'm writing a bug-tracking backend based on MongoDB and I'm facing a problem:

My main collections are:

- **User**: represents a user in the system
- **Project**: represents a project (each contains an array of permitted users - references to User)
- **Bugs**: list of bugs (each contains a reference to the parent project)

On the main page, I would like to display the latest 10 bugs from all projects the current user is part of.

It seems like right now I have to first query for the list of projects the user is part of, then then use this list (with the $in operator) to query for latest 10 bugs which belong to those projects.

I was wondering whether there is a better way to represent my data to make this query simpler or is this the only reasonable solution.

Thanks!

Comment: One option would be to model the data differently using embedded documents i.e., Have `bugs` as sub-documents within `project` collection or vice-versa. More details [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).If your use-case doesn't permit such modeling, then I guess there is no other option.

Comment: @AnandJayabalan There might be a lot of bugs, thus I cannot embed them inside the project itself - they have to exists in a separate collection.